# Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspat': could not resolve com.nineoldandroidlibs:library:2.4.0

Tags: android, gradle

**Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspat': could not resolve com.nineoldandroidlibs:library:2.4.0** 
 I am trying to import fancy button and pie chart libraries but i am getting the error mention above. I tried everything but nothing works. 
 **Following is my gradle file of project**

```
    buildscript {

    repositories {
      google()
//       maven { url "https://maven.google.com"}
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
     google()
 //   maven { url "https://maven.google.com"}
    //maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Following is my Gradle Project file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hamzanaeem.gasapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.blackfizz:eazegraph:1.2.2@aar'
    compile 'com.github.medyo:fancybuttons:1.8.4'
}
```

Please help I`ve already tried all of the solution from stackoverflow too.
Thanks

Comment: Try to restart android studio , because its working fine in my project ,its not throwing any errors

Comment: just did but the error is still there

Comment: Your min SDK version is 16 so you don't need nine old androids.

Comment: but what about the other two ?

Comment: replace this in your graddle-wrapper.properties to distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip

Comment: nope nothing works thanks for help though